# MySQL showing sum 0

Tags: mysql

So I have a table holding a set of order items, the order items table keeps track of how many of a particular item were included in a particular order.  Below is a simplified version of the table for use within this example.

**Order item table**

```
order_item_id : int
order_item_item_id : int
order_item_quantity : int
order_item_order_id : int
```

**Order table**

```
order_id : int
order_date : date
```

I am trying to perform a single query which will average the sales of particular order_item_item_id's on a per week, per month and all time basis.

Currently my query is as follows

```
SELECT totalAvg.item 

ROUND(AVG(totalAvg.total)+0.4999999, 0) AS totalAverage,  
ROUND(AVG(monthAvg.total)+0.4999999, 0) AS monthAverage, 
ROUND(AVG(weekAvg.total)+0.4999999, 0) AS weekAverage from

(SELECT orderitem.order_item_item_id AS item, SUM(orderitem.order_item_quantity) AS total,
 DATE(`order`.order_date) AS date FROM orderitem, `order` WHERE orderitem.order_item_order_id = 
`order`.order_id GROUP BY DATE(`order`.order_date), order_item_item_id) AS totalAvg,

(SELECT orderitem.order_item_item_id AS item, SUM(orderitem.order_item_quantity) AS total, 
DATE(`order`.order_date) AS date FROM orderitem, `order` WHERE orderitem.order_item_order_id =
`order`.order_id AND `order`.order_date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 week) GROUP BY 
DATE(`order`.order_date), order_item_item_id) AS weekAvg,

(SELECT orderitem.order_item_item_id AS item, SUM(orderitem.order_item_quantity) AS total,
DATE(`order`.order_date) AS date FROM orderitem, `order` WHERE orderitem.order_item_order_id = 
`order`.order_id AND `order`.order_date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) GROUP BY 
DATE(`order`.order_date), order_item_item_id) AS monthAvg,

WHERE totalAvg.item = monthAvg.item AND
monthAvg.item = weekAvg.item 
GROUP BY item
```

The problem with this is that if an item does not exist in the weekAvg table then no results are printed for totalAvg or monthAvg.  How can I go about doing this within a single statement?

**Sample data**

```
{order_id : 5, order_date : 02/02/2013}
{order_id : 6, order_date : 13/03/2013}

{order_item_id : 1, order_item_order_id : 5, order_item_item_id : 1, order_item_quantity : 3}
{order_item_id : 2, order_item_order_id : 6, order_item_item_id : 1, order_item_quantity : 4}
```

The current output would return nothing since the weekly report does not have an entry for an order item with id 1.  I am trying to get around this so that it woudl output the following

```
totalAverage = 3.5
monthAverage = 4
weekAverage = 0
```

The values are calculated as follows:

Total average = total number of a particular item sold divided by the number of days that item was sold on.

Month and week values are the same as the previous calculation but with a time restriction so that the order must have been placed within the last week/month.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [outer joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) to connect totalAvg to monthAvg and weekAvg. You can use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to make sure you get 0 instead of NULL for empty week or month values.

You should also use ANSI join syntax. It's less error prone and more readable.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT totalAvg.item,
ROUND(AVG(totalAvg.total)+0.4999999, 0) AS totalAverage,  
COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(monthAvg.total)+0.4999999, 0),0) AS monthAverage, 
COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(weekAvg.total)+0.4999999, 0),) AS weekAverage 
from
(
  SELECT orderitem.order_item_item_id AS item, 
    SUM(orderitem.order_item_quantity) AS total,
    DATE(`order`.order_date) AS date 
  FROM orderitem
    inner join `order` on orderitem.order_item_order_id = `order`.order_id 
  GROUP BY DATE(`order`.order_date), order_item_item_id
) AS totalAvg
left outer join
(
  SELECT orderitem.order_item_item_id AS item, 
    SUM(orderitem.order_item_quantity) AS total, 
    DATE(`order`.order_date) AS date 
  FROM orderitem
    inner join `order` on orderitem.order_item_order_id = `order`.order_id 
  WHERE `order`.order_date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 week) 
  GROUP BY 
  DATE(`order`.order_date), order_item_item_id
) AS weekAvg on weekAvg.item = totalAvg.item
left outer join
(
  SELECT orderitem.order_item_item_id AS item, 
    SUM(orderitem.order_item_quantity) AS total,
    DATE(`order`.order_date) AS date 
  FROM orderitem
    inner join `order` on orderitem.order_item_order_id = `order`.order_id 
  WHERE `order`.order_date > date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) 
  GROUP BY DATE(`order`.order_date), order_item_item_id
) AS monthAvg on monthAvg.item = totalAvg.item
GROUP BY item
```

Comment: I think I am getting confused, probably by the fact I went for a bloated (although cut down) example.  Now I am trying to put it into the actual version and trying to figure out what you have done but can not get it to work.  Can you maybe show an example of the coallese, inner joins and left outer joins while explaining what it does/how it works?  I for the life of me can not work it out which is very frustrating to say the least :P